# tar Linux command exluding subdirectories´ hierarchies (but including their files)

Tags: linux, file, command, directory, tar

I have the folder `a` with two files (1,2), and the subfolder `b` with another two files (3,4).

I ´d like to tar `a` with '1,2,3,4' files in the tar file, but not including `b`.

(By default (`tar cvf`), `b` is added, and '3,4' are inside `b`. How can I do it?)

Thanks

Comment: Posible dupe / following question can be helpful [tar files only no directories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/tar-files-only-no-directories)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tardy/ could be relevant to postprocess your tar archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a script like this:

```
# ! /bin/sh
files=`cat list.list`
tarname="test.tar"
tarpath=`pwd`
#create empty tar
tar -cvf $tarpath/$tarname --files-from /dev/null

for curr_file in $files
do
   #add each file separatly
   cd `dirname $curr_file`
   tar -uvf $tarpath/$tarname `basename $curr_file`
   cd -
done
```

and create the filelist with a command like this:

```
find -type f > list.list
```